# using torrent encryption

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

everyone, I have some problem with my torrent, I encrypted my torrent but still can't download files from the net, what may be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First, some clarification on terms.

You are using a BitTorrent client and you have a problem with your BitTorrent setup. A torrent is a file describing a particular set of files that you download from a site and/or the small network of peers/servers that transfer that file. Usually, people say it's that site's torrent, not "my torrent". People who say "my torrent" are usually the uploader of that torrent.

Anyway, you should check your firewall settings and see if uTorrent is allowed through. Also, give more info on what uTorrent is yelling about in the info tab of the torrent.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to forward your ports. Look at this, it may help: http://portforward.com/